# How do I include key and value pairs in jq CSV output from a nested NDJSON?

Tags: json, database, header, jq, export-to-csv

I want to export my NDJSON data into a CSV format with headers and key-value pairs.

Sample Data:

```
{"name":"//storage.googleapis.com/testing-list-api","asset_type":"storage.googleapis.com/Bucket","resource":{"version":"v1","discovery_document_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest","discovery_name":"Bucket","parent":"//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/503672515986","data":{"acl":[],"autoclass":{},"billing":{},"cors":[],"defaultObjectAcl":[],"encryption":{},"etag":"CAE=","iamConfiguration":{"bucketPolicyOnly":{"enabled":true,"lockedTime":"2023-05-10T15:38:33.688Z"},"publicAccessPrevention":"enforced","uniformBucketLevelAccess":{"enabled":true,"lockedTime":"2023-05-10T15:38:33.688Z"}},"id":"testing-list-api","kind":"storage#bucket","labels":{"application":"gcs-bucket","testing":"api"},"lifecycle":{"rule":[]},"location":"US","locationType":"multi-region","logging":{},"metageneration":1,"name":"testing-list-api","owner":{},"projectNumber":503672515986,"retentionPolicy":{},"selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/testing-list-api","storageClass":"STANDARD","timeCreated":"2023-02-09T15:38:33.688Z","updated":"2023-02-09T15:38:33.688Z","versioning":{},"website":{}},"location":"us"},"ancestors":["projects/503672515986"],"update_time":"2023-02-09T15:38:33.688Z"}
```

Currently, here is the command I am running -

```
cat gcp_resources.ndjson | jq -r '[.name,.asset_type,.resource.data.labels[]//"null"]|@csv' >> filtered_data.txt
```

And here is the output I am seeing -

```
"//storage.googleapis.com/testing-list-api","storage.googleapis.com/Bucket","gcs-bucket","api"
```

However, I want to include the label keys along with their values and I want to print the headers on the first row, something like resource_name, asset_type, labels. So expected output would look like -

```
resource_name   asset_type    labels

"//storage.googleapis.com/testing-list-api","storage.googleapis.com/Bucket","application:gcs-bucket","testing:api"
```

Any suggestions on how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Prepend the headers as array, and append `@csv` for CSV output, i.e. `jq -r '["resource_name","asset_type","labels"], [.name,.asset_type,.resource.data.labels[]//"null"] | @csv' cvs_gcp_resources.ndjson`

Comment: @pmf
Since my data has multiple entries and some of them don't have labels (null values), here is the output I am seeing - 

`
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
"//pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/example-project/topics/kafka_sub","pubsub.googleapis.com/Topic","gke-kafka"
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
"//storage.googleapis.com/dataproc-example","storage.googleapis.com/Bucket","null"
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
"resource_name","asset_type","labels"
`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Re "my data has multiple entries and some of them don't have labels": Then please provide a sample with multiple entries, including ones with no label, and ideally excluding all the other parts that are not affected (to minimize the sample data size).

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with the three-part header shown in the Q, then you could use the following:

```
  ["resource_name","asset_type", "labels"],
  
  [.name,.asset_type, 
   ( .resource.data.labels // empty | to_entries[] | "\(.key):\(.value)") ]
  | @csv
```

A similar option would be to compact all the `label:value` components into a single CSV field so that the file is indeed in a standard (rectangular) CSV format.

On the other hand, if you want the headers to reflect the labels in some manner, you will have to specify your requirements in more detail.